# What does this recursive react using useState fail?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making tree viewer in React. Each level of the tree is a `<details>` tag. I recursively create the tree. At each level I have

```
// psuedo code

function NodeWithChilden({thing}) {
  return (
    <detail>
      <summary>{thing.name}<summary>
      <div>
         {thing.children.map((child,  ndx) => <Node node={child} key={`c${ndx}`} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Node({thing}) {
  return (isLeaf) ? (
     <div>{thing.name}: {thing.value}</div>
  ) : (
     <ThingWithChildren value={thing}>
  );
}
```

Then, do the `NodeWithChildren` I add some state via `useState` for the `<details>` tag
and since I'm tracking `open` there's no need to render the children if it's not open.

```
function NodeWithChilden({thing}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  return (
    <detail open={open} onToggle={e => setOpen(e.target.open)}>
      <summary>{thing.name}<summary>
      (open && <div>
         {thing.children.map((child,  ndx) => <Node node={child} key={`c${ndx}`} />)}
      </div>)
    </div>
  );
}
```

The issue is, when I click a child, it closes all the parents!

[image]

What am I not understanding about react and hooks?

[Here's a codesandbox of the code that's not working](https://codesandbox.io/s/clicking-a-child-closes-all-parents-luz4h2?file=/src/App.tsx).  (also pasted the code below)

Click any of the child `<detail>` tags and the parent closes too

Note: I tried to repo even smaller but [this one is not failing](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-the-details-tag-by-itself-9lz6l0)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I thought maybe it had to do with adding and removing comoponents so I made a version that just hides elements (so regardless of the state of the `<details>` elements all elements exist. [It has the same issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/clicking-a-child-closes-all-parents-keep-all-elements-always-kdi8wk).

Full code below:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define */

import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

enum ValueType {
  kBasic,
  kObject
}

const getValueType = (data: any) => {
  if (typeof data === "string") {
    return ValueType.kBasic;
  } else {
    return ValueType.kObject;
  }
};

interface JsonValueObjectValueProps {
  propName: string;
  value: any;
}

function JsonValueObjectValueBasic({
  propName,
  value
}: JsonValueObjectValueProps) {
  return (
    <div className="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value">
      <div className="spector2-jsonvalue-key">{propName}:</div>
      <div className="spector2-jsonvalue-value">
        <JsonValue data={value} />;
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function JsonValueObjectValueObject({
  propName,
  value
}: JsonValueObjectValueProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const objectHasKeys = Object.keys(value).length > 0;
  return (
    <details
      open={open}
      onToggle={(e) => setOpen((e.target as HTMLDetailsElement).open)}
      className="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable"
    >
      <summary>
        {propName}: {objectHasKeys ? (open ? `{` : `{...},`) : `{},`}
      </summary>

      {open && objectHasKeys && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable-value">
            <JsonValue data={value} />
          </div>
          <div className="spector2-jsonvalue-close-symbol">{"},"}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </details>
  );
}

function JsonValueObjectValue({ propName, value }: JsonValueObjectValueProps) {
  const valueType = getValueType(value);
  switch (valueType) {
    default:
    case ValueType.kBasic:
      return <JsonValueObjectValueBasic value={value} propName={propName} />;
    case ValueType.kObject:
      return <JsonValueObjectValueObject value={value} propName={propName} />;
  }
}

export function JsonValueObject({ data }: { data: Record<string, any> }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value], ndx) => (
        <JsonValueObjectValue key={`e${ndx}`} propName={key} value={value} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export function JsonValue({ depth, data }: { depth?: number; data: any }) {
  if (typeof data === "string") {
    return <div>&quot;{data}&quot;</div>;
  } else {
    return <JsonValueObject data={data} />;
  }
}

const json = {
  name: "Tami",
  relatives: {
    Carole: {
      relationship: "mom"
    },
    Terry: {
      relationship: "dad"
    },
    Brandy: {
      relationship: "dog"
    }
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <JsonValue data={json} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and some css otherwise it's hard to see

```
.App {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-key {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-key-value {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-value {
  display: flex;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable-value {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-close-symbol {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparenty the issue is somehow the event is propogating up to the parents. Adding an `event.stopPropagation()` in the `onToggle` solved the issue

```
<detail open={open} onToggle={e => {
   e.stopPropogation();
   setOpen(e.target.open);
}}>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/clicking-a-child-closes-all-parents-stop-propagation-itqedz?file=/src/App.tsx

It's not clear if that's a bug in the browser or react. I tried Safari, Chrome, and Firefox and it happens in all of them.

I also copied the html react generated into a plain html file and tested it outside of react. It does not have the issue

```js
document.querySelectorAll('details').forEach(elem => {
  // simulate react updating the element
  elem.addEventListener('toggle', e => {
    e.target.open = e.target.open;
  })
})
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-key {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-key-value {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-value {
  display: flex;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable-value {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.spector2-jsonvalue-close-symbol {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="App">
    <div>
      <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value">
        <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key">name:</div>
        <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-value">
          <div>"Tami"</div>;
        </div>
      </div>
      <details class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable" open="">
        <summary>relatives: {</summary>
        <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable-value">
          <div>
            <details open="" class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable">
              <summary>Carole: {</summary>
              <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable-value">
                <div>
                  <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value">
                    <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key">relationship:</div>
                    <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-value">
                      <div>"mom"</div>;
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-close-symbol">},</div>
            </details>
            <details open="" class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable">
              <summary>Terry: {</summary>
              <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable-value">
                <div>
                  <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value">
                    <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key">relationship:</div>
                    <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-value">
                      <div>"dad"</div>;
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-close-symbol">},</div>
            </details>
            <details open="" class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable">
              <summary>Brandy: {</summary>
              <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value-expandable-value">
                <div>
                  <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key-value">
                    <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-key">relationship:</div>
                    <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-value">
                      <div>"dog"</div>;
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-close-symbol">},</div>
            </details>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spector2-jsonvalue-close-symbol">},</div>
      </details>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Turns out it's a known bug in React: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22718